# MPC Private Key generation with ERC-6492 authentication

Tags: erc-6492, mpc, multi-party-computation

I'm trying to generate a **consistent signature from a Smart Wallet**, as I need to derive application-logic keys from it.The flow is

- I provide a static message
- message is signed
- from the signature I derive application-logic keys

Since it's a Smart Wallet, it returns an **ERC-6492 signature**. This type of signature can change over time (change of owners, etc), plus there's not a standard way to extract the raw signature from the hex data returned (since it's not the goal of the ERC, while it offers a standard method to verify it).

My idea is then to put an **MPC-powered middleware**, like Privy. The flow will be

- get the ERC-6492 signature
- auth that wallet to the MPC counterparties using the signature
- reconstruct the private key from MPC shards and then use it to generate a consistent signature

I need to do that in a JS env that can also run not in a browser (no DOM access). While conceptually I'm sure it's possible, I haven't found a way to do it (talking specifically about Privy, for example, I have also explored the @privy-io/js-sdk-core repo with no success).

From an external perspective, it's like having an "ERC-6492" login method to an MPC pool. **Any suggestion of tools or a possible way to get that done?**